# About symmetry, braids, and pseudo-functors.

Tags: ct.category-theory, braided-tensor-categories

Let $(\mathcal{C}, \otimes, I)$ a monoidal category, and let $\mathbb{B}(\mathcal{C})$ the bicategory (with only one object and $(\mathcal{C}, \otimes, I)$ as (monoidal) category of morphisms and cells).
Let $\mathbb{B}(\mathcal{C})^{op}$ the dual respect morphisms (i.e. twisting $\otimes$, and inverting canonical isomorphisms,  in the monoidal category  $\mathcal{C}$).
A pseudo-functor (see [ncatlab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pseudofunctor)) $(Q, \theta): \mathbb{B}(\mathcal{C})\to \mathbb{B}(\mathcal{C})^{op}$ that fixes objects,  morphisms, and cells, and is unitary (i.e. the canonical isomorphisms $Q(I)\cong I$ is the identity)
is a family of isomorphism $q_{A, B}^{-1}: B\otimes A= Q(B)\otimes Q(A)\cong Q(A\otimes B)= A\otimes B $
such that:

U1) $q_{A, I}\circ r_A= l_A$

U2) $q_{I, A}\circ l_A= r_A$

where $r_A: A \cong A\otimes I$, $l_A: A \cong I\otimes A$ canonically.

and with:

$a\circ q_{C\otimes B, A}^{-1}\circ A\otimes q_{C, B}^{-1}= q_{C, B\otimes A}^{-1}\circ q_{B, A}^{-1}\otimes C\circ a^{-1}:
A\otimes (B\otimes C) \to C\otimes (B\otimes A) $

or equivalently:

$A\otimes q_{C, B}\circ q_{C\otimes B, A}=
a\circ q_{B, A}\otimes C\circ q_{C, B\otimes A}\circ a
 : (C\otimes B)\otimes A) \to A\otimes (B\otimes C) $

If we further require  that  $Q^{op}\circ Q=1_{\mathbb{B}(\mathcal{C})}$ then: $q_{A,B}\circ q_{B, A}=1$.

***I ask***:

1) is a such pseudofunctor $Q$ a symmetry?

2) What about a generalization to braids (i.e. how describe a braid as a pseudo-functor)?

Note that exist a coherence theorem: any diagram of canonical isomorphisms (from monoidal structure or from pseudofunctor data) commute

Comment: Opps, I forget a comma "," between "symmetry" and "braids" in the title.

Comment: You can edit the title!

Comment: Ok, I have the answere now.

Comment: Would you mind posting the answer then?

Comment: I agree with Turion. This is a reasonable question and it would be better to have it answered here than for this to linger without an answer