# A question about braiding represented as pseudofunctors

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

I just asked a very similar question here ([About symmetry, braids, and pseudo-functors.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115818/about-symmetry-braids-and-pseudo-functors)), still now I dont get a answere. I hope  to express myself more clearly and correctly this time.

Let $(\mathcal{C}, \otimes, I)$ (or simply $\mathcal{C}$) a monoidal category, we have the tensor-dual $(\mathcal{C}, \otimes^{op}, I)$ (or simply ${}^{op}\mathcal{C}$) with the some objects, with $A\otimes^{op} B:=B\otimes A$ and with the associativity constraint inverted, and unitary isomorphisms $r, l$
exchanged.

I call **pseudo-symmetry** a strong monoidal functor (called tensor functor in [BTC]) $Q: {}^{op}\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{C} $ that is the identity on the objects, this is a collection of isomorphisms $c_{A, B}: A\otimes B= Q(B\otimes^{op}A)\cong Q(B)\otimes Q(A)= B\otimes A$ such that $c_{A, I}$ and $c_{I, A}$ are coherent with the unitary isomphisms $r_A, l_A$ and such that (see for example [BTC] p. 25):

$(A\otimes B)\otimes C\xrightarrow{c\otimes 1}(B\otimes A)\otimes C\xrightarrow{c}
C\otimes (B\otimes A)$ is equal to:

$(A\otimes B)\otimes C\xrightarrow{a}A\otimes (B\otimes C)\xrightarrow{1\otimes c}
A\otimes (C\otimes B)\xrightarrow{c}
(C\otimes B)\otimes A$.

We have that if $c$ is a braiding on $\mathcal{C}$ then its also a pseudo-symmetry.

***I ask: Is the converse true***?

PS. A monidal category is representable as a one-object bicategory, and  (strong) monoidal functor is just a pseudo-funtor, and there is a coherence theorem for pseudfuntor: "all diagrams of canonical constraints (frome the bicategories and pseudofuntor) commuting" but this need a little warning: this is relate to diagrams in a free construction, no on the codomain bicategory,  for example consider the classical identity for a monoidal symmetry:  $1_{A\otimes B}: A\otimes B\xrightarrow{c_{A\otimes B}}B\otimes A\xrightarrow{c_{A\otimes B}}A\otimes B$ in the free structure formalism these two  morphism corrispond to   $c_{A\otimes B}: Q(B\otimes^{op} A)\to Q(B)\otimes Q(A)$ and
$c_{B\otimes A}: Q(A\otimes^{op} B)\to Q(A)\otimes Q(B)$ and these aren't composable, the equality
 $Q(A\otimes^{op} B)=A\otimes B= Q(B\otimes^{op} A)$ is true in  $\mathcal{C}$ BUT NO in the free structure  which is based the coherence criterion.

References:

[BTC] Braided Tensor Categories, Ross Street, Andre Joyal.  Advances in Math. 102 p. 20-78.

Comment: Have you seen the paper ["Iterated monoidal categories"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.45.290&rep=rep1&type=pdf)? Their approach is to describe pseudomonoids in monoidal categories; see also about the [higher generalizations](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/iterated+monoidal+category) in ncatlab

Comment: Consider a one object category, with only one non identity morphism $f$, satisfying $ff = 1$, with the trivial monoidal structure. $f$ determines a strong monoidal structure on the identity functor, however it is not a braiding.